# c# - File not found exception - System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.0

Tags: c#, mongodb

As soon as I instantiate the c# driver in my windows service with

`MongoDbClient = new MongoClient(Settings.Default.OpsMgrConnStr);`

my server process is crashing with an error

```
Error: FileNotFoundException: Die Datei oder Assembly "System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
```

This happens since I had to update in NuGet all my libraries and dependencies.

Some research (actually some hours.....) showed me the following [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2033) filed in the mongodb jira. I need a workaround, can't wait for months until V2.6 is released.

Can anybody help and tell me how I need to setup my `app.config` file to sort this out??

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have .Net 4 installed?  That'd be the first thing I checked.

Comment: Of course, it was working BEFORE I have done my NuGet updates! According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed) article I have 4.7.1 on my system. It is a dependency issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the case when assembly binding redirect should be used. Add following section to your app.config:

```
<configuration>

  <!-- ... -->

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.1.1.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

In `newVersion` attribute put the actual version that is currently shipped with your application.

Comment: I cannot currently test it, because I have removed the libs causing the problem (was commons.logging which is used by several libs but in different versions). I will reactivate it as soon as I have time, but I accept your answer since it looks quite plausible. I have such entries in other projects too. Thanks anyway!